# How do I cut a string already separated by spaces?

Tags: command-line, string, cut

Lets say there's a string like this

```
test="1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9/0"
```

They are separated by spaces, as well as '/'.
I want to return a result like this by taking the second field of each string segment.

```
2 5 8
```

Is it possible to do this with cut? Or do I need something else?

```
newstring=$(echo $test | cut -d "/" -f2)
```

returns only

```
2
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is replace spaces with newlines and then use `awk` or `cut`. Then, replace newlines with spaces. You'll want to `echo` the entire thing to get a final newline again:

```
$ echo $(echo "$test" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F'/' '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
2 5 8
```

Or

```
$ echo $(echo "$test" | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -d/ -f 2 | tr '\n' ' ')
2 5 8
```

You could also just use `perl`:

```
$ echo "$test" | perl -lane 's#.*?/(.+?)/.*#$1# for @F; print "@F"' 
2 5 8
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
$ echo ${${${=test}#*/}%%/*}
2 5 8
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$test" | sed 's|[^ /]*/\([^/]*\)[^ ]*|\1|g'
2 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for `cut`

```
cut -d/ -f2,4,6 --output-delimiter=' ' <<<"$test"
```